# How to build boost 1.69.0 for Android with NDK r18b using moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android?

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

I tried to use https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android to compile boost for Android. It reports 1.69.0 is supported for NDK r18b. I'm under Windows 7.

I encountered many problems, some of them I could fix, but finally I could not get anything compiled:

- Installed MinGW
- Installed MySYS
- Added MySYS to PATH
- Ran build-android.bat
- Got error: `<path to NDK r18b> is not a valid NDK root`
  -> Thats because the script checks if ndk-build exists
  -> Replaced "ndk-build" by "ndk-build.cmd" in script
- Then I got error: `sed: invalid option --E`
  -> Removed -E option from sed at line 241
- Note that I see a lot of non-blocking warnings `expr: warning: unportable BRE:`
- Then I got the error: `Undefined or not supported Android NDK version: Pkg.Revision = 18.1.5063045` (most likely due to this -E option I just removed)
  -> Replaced `"16.0"|....|"18.1")` by `*)` and removed `*)` original statement at lines 301/307
- Then it reported curl was missing, I installed curl and added it to my path
- Finally boost 1.69.0 download started
- Then, I got tones of errors and nothing got built:

> ```
> C:/dev/boost/Boost-for-Android-master/boost_1_69_0/tools/build/src/tools\common.
> jam:979: in toolset-tag
> *** argument error
> * rule numbers.less ( n1 n2 )
> * called with: ( 3 )
> * missing argument n2 C:/dev/boost/Boost-for-Android-master/boost_1_69_0/tools/build/src/util\numbers.
> jam:66:see definition of rule 'numbers.less' being called
> ```

and:

> ```
> am:305: Unescaped special character in argument
> <compileflags>$(AndroidNDKRoot)/
> toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/${PlatformOS}-x86_64 Performing
> configuration checks
> ```

and finally:

> ```
> ERROR: Failed to build boost for android for x86_64!
> ```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

Edit: According to https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android/issues/156, there is a problem with boost 1.69.0. So I tried with 1.68.0, then I get different errors:

> ```
> C:\dev\boost\Boost-for-Android-master\boost_1_68_0\tools/build/src\user-config.j
> am:70: Unescaped special character in argument <compileflags>$(AndroidNDKRoot)/t
> oolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/${PlatformOS}-x86_64
> ```

and

> ```
> error: No best alternative for libs/context/build/asm_sources
>     next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
> ...
>     next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <architecture>combined <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
>     not matched
> ```

and finally

> ```
> clang-linux.archive ..\build\build\arm64-v8a\boost\bin.v2\libs\atomic\build\clan
> g-linux-arm64v8a\release\link-static\target-os-android\threading-multi\libboost_
> atomic-clang-mt-a64-1_68.a
> '"ranlib"' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
> ou externe, un programme ex'cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
>
>     "c:/Android2/android-ndk-r18b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/ll
> vm-ar"  rc "..\build\build\arm64-v8a\boost\bin.v2\libs\atomic\build\clang-linux-
> arm64v8a\release\link-static\target-os-android\threading-multi\libboost_atomic-c
> lang-mt-a64-1_68.a" "..\build\build\arm64-v8a\boost\bin.v2\libs\atomic\build\cla
> ng-linux-arm64v8a\release\link-static\target-os-android\threading-multi\lockpool
> .o"
>     "ranlib" "..\build\build\arm64-v8a\boost\bin.v2\libs\atomic\build\clang-linu
> x-arm64v8a\release\link-static\target-os-android\threading-multi\libboost_atomic
> -clang-mt-a64-1_68.a"
>
> ...failed clang-linux.archive ..\build\build\arm64-v8a\boost\bin.v2\libs\atomic\
> build\clang-linux-arm64v8a\release\link-static\target-os-android\threading-multi
> \libboost_atomic-clang-mt-a64-1_68.a...
> ...removing ..\build\build\arm64-v8a\boost\bin.v2\libs\atomic\build\clang-linux-
> arm64v8a\release\link-static\target-os-android\threading-multi\libboost_atomic-c
> lang-mt-a64-1_68.a
> ```